# Apache Reverse-Proxy with Auth Form not passing credentials to proxied server

Tags: apache, forms-authentication, reverse-proxy

I am working on a reverse proxy solution (CentOS 7 + Apache w/ pcs + Pacemaker + Corosync for HA), which is working wonderfully.

I need to add authentication which gets passed to one of the proxied servers.  Using basic LDAP Authentication, I can get this to work:

```
Listen 10.2.0.11:80
<VirtualHost 10.2.0.11:80>
  <Proxy balancer://authweb>
    BalancerMember http://win-web01
  </Proxy>

  ServerName authweb
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"

  ProxyPreserveHost On

  <Location />
    SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
    AuthName "Password Protected.  Enter AD User & Password."
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthBasicAuthoritative Off
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://10.2.0.7:3268/dc=domain,dc=test?userPrincipalName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
    AuthLDAPBindDN "administrator@DOMAIN.TEST"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "P@ssw0rd"

    Session On
    SessionCookieName session path=/

    Require valid-user
  </Location>

  ProxyPass / balancer://authweb/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://authweb/
</VirtualHost>
```

This configuration works nicely.  An Auth dialog box pops up, accepts the credentials, and passes the credentials to the server behind the proxy - in this case, an IIS server.

What we want to do is to use a nice looking form for the login, instead of the Auth pop-up dialog.  However, I am struggling to get it to work.  Here what I have:

```
Listen 10.2.0.11:80
<VirtualHost 10.2.0.11:80>
  <Proxy balancer://authweb>
    BalancerMember http://win-web01
  </Proxy>

  ServerName authweb

  ProxyRequests Off
  ProxyPreserveHost On
  SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
  <Location />
   SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
   AuthName "Password Protected.  Enter AD User & Password."
   AuthType form
   AuthFormProvider ldap
   AuthFormAuthoritative Off
   AuthFormLoginRequiredLocation "/login.html"

   AuthLDAPURL "ldap://10.2.0.7:3268/dc=domain,dc=test?userPrincipalName?sub?(objectClass=*)"
   AuthLDAPBindDN "administrator@DOMAIN.TEST"
   AuthLDAPBindPassword "P@ssw0rd"

   Session On
   SessionCookieName session path=/

   Require valid-user

   ErrorDocument 401 "/login.html"

  </Location>
  <Location /login.html>
    SetEnv proxy-chain-auth On
    AuthType None
    AuthName "Login"
    Require all granted

    ProxyPass !
  </Location>

  ProxyPass / balancer://authweb/
  ProxyPassReverse / balancer://authweb/
</VirtualHost>
```

This *almost* works.  The Apache server displays the Auth form and accepts the post and proxies to the IIS server.  However, it is not passing the credentials to IIS, so I am prompted with an Auth pop-up dialog for the IIS credentials.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  I have done a lot of web searching and haven't found anything yet.

I know that functionality like this is possible with solutions from places like F5 and Kemp, but we don't have the budget for that, nor do we need that big of a system.  However, I'm not sure exactly how they do it.  It's possible that they have built custom modules for handling it and I'm chasing my tail, but I hope not.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Eric

Comment: Just to be clear, you want Apache to present an authentication page, and then sent that info to IIS? Why not let IIS take care of this authentication? It is what it does anyway now right? I think you need NTLM in Apache (https://bloke.org/linux/ntlm-authentication-active-directory-on-apache-linux/), YMMV.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what we want.  Currently, we have a reverse-proxy server in front of a pair of SharePoint servers, which have forms authentication turned on.  The problem is that the SharePoint servers have both internal and external access and SharePoint treats the same logon/account as two different users with regards to the profiles it builds. I have been advised that the best solution is an authenticating reverse-proxy, then all users only have one profile.  Due to budgetary constraints, F5 & Kemp solutions are not feasible.  So I'm trying to make one.

Comment: See this post for more information:  https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/d436da75-b0f6-4e38-9dab-7e6b28e1e650/sharepoint-2013-with-fba-creating-second-user-profile?forum=sharepointadmin